# Combined Tables Not Centering Correctly with ACM

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, acm

I'm trying to put two tables together, so that they sit immediately, with ACM's template and I'm having a problem.  The tables will sit next to once another, but the first table will be too far to the left, with the second table sitting in the correct position.  The tables will then be put on their own page, rather than sit with the text, regardless of how I attempt to position them.

Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}  

\begin{document}

\title{Example}

\maketitle

\begin{table*}
  \caption{Power Measurements, 1 and 2 Bids}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular} {| c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
        \textbf{Number of Bids} & \multicolumn{3} {|c|} {\textbf{1}} & \multicolumn{3} {|c|} {\textbf{2}} \\
    \hline
        Trial       & 1      & 2      & 3       &   1   & 2       & 3    \\
    \hline
        Duration    & 5m 59s & 16m 6s & 5m 57s  & 6m 6s & 15m 37s & 6m 59s  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \newline  \vspace*{1 mm} \newline
  \caption{Power Measurements, 3 and 4}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular} {| c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
        \textbf{Number of Bids} & \multicolumn{3} {|c|} {\textbf{3}} & \multicolumn{3} {|c|} {\textbf{4}} \\
    \hline
        Trial       & 1      & 2      & 3       &   1   & 2       & 3    \\
    \hline
        Duration    & 7m 25s & 16m 7s & 10m 57s & 5m 49s & 16m 8s & 7m 24s  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}  
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure how I need to correct this issue.

Comment: \caption causes a paragraph break.  You need to put both a tabular and its caption inside a minipage (using 0.5\textwidth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{subcaption}

\newcommand{\tabc}{\stepcounter{table}}
% \tabc command will be used to increment counter
% in subtable.
% add this command in the end of caption of a 
% subtable but leaving the subcaption of the first subtable.


\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{Table~\thetable}
\begin{document}

\title{Example}

\maketitle

\section{one}
\begin{table*}[!h]
  \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
  \caption{Power Measurements, 1 and 2 Bids}% no \tabc command here
  \centering
  \begin{tabular} {| c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
        \textbf{Number of Bids} & \multicolumn{3} {|c|} {\textbf{1}} & \multicolumn{3} {|c|} {\textbf{2}} \\
    \hline
        Trial       & 1      & 2      & 3       &   1   & 2       & 3    \\
    \hline
        Duration    & 5m 59s & 16m 6s & 5m 57s  & 6m 6s & 15m 37s & 6m 59s  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
  \\[1mm]
  \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
  \caption{Power Measurements, 3 and 4 \tabc} % \tabc command here and
  % in the subtables following this one in this table environment
  \centering
  \begin{tabular} {| c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
        \textbf{Number of Bids} & \multicolumn{3} {|c|} {\textbf{3}} & \multicolumn{3} {|c|} {\textbf{4}} \\
    \hline
        Trial       & 1      & 2      & 3       &   1   & 2       & 3    \\
    \hline
        Duration    & 7m 25s & 16m 7s & 10m 57s & 5m 49s & 16m 8s & 7m 24s  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
  % Do not use caption here
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That corrected the positioning, but unfortunately, the ACM style guide explicitly states that tables have to be titled 'Table 1', et cetera, not (a), and (b).  Know any way to correct that?

Comment: Now check out the new answer and take care of the limitations mentioned.